# How to apply overconstrained planning in OptaPlanner in a better way?

Tags: java, drools, optaplanner

In meeting scheduling example I'm trying to apply overconstrained planning. I've checked documentation and also answers in stackoverflow, then applied **nullable = true** to the @PlanningVariable which is in the MeetingAssignment:

```
   @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = { "roomRange" }, nullable = true)
   public Room getRoom() {
      return room;
   }
```

Also I've added a rule to the drool:

```
rule "Assign Every Person To A Room"
    when
        $meetingAssignment : MeetingAssignment(room == null)
    then
        scoreHolder.addMediumConstraintMatch(kcontext, -100);
end
```

My scoreholder is: **HardMediumSoftScoreHolder**

However when I run the application, only one person out of six different person can be assigned. This doesn't occure if nullable is false and every person can be assigned. Also this six person doens't break hard constraint.
Do you have any idea for overconstraint planning solution problem?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I've found a solution. I've only had hard and medium constraint panalties. I've changed my all mediumConstraint penalties as softConstraint except "Assign Every Person To A Room" rule. Now I can assign every person.

Thanks